# How to install Android SDK?

Tags: 10.10, android, eclipse, ide

How to install **Android SDK** from `android-sdk_r10-linux_x86.tgz` in Ubuntu 10.10 for using in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
The process is quite straightforward.

Ubuntu does not have yet the latest package for Eclipse, therefore, it is advised to install Eclipse by downloading it from http://www.eclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

Taker a look at [this document](http://www.futuredesktop.com/maverick/android/developing_android_apps_on_ubuntu.html).
It will show you how to install the latest Eclipse IDE and Android SDK + setup.